# Proactive notification for thermostat in google smart home

Tags: actions-on-google, google-smart-home

We are trying to implement temperature monitoring system with our devices. The goal is to have an alert when the temperature exceeds/goes below the set points.

I can see that we can set the temperature limits with the [thermostattemperaturesetrange trait](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/traits/temperaturesetting#action.devices).

But there is no way to send a proactive notification with the trait.
Also, it automatically works with Google's Nest thermostats [as mentioned here](https://support.google.com/googlenest/answer/9249790#zippy=%2Cset-safety-temperatures). Just wondering how one would achieve with custom devices.

The [sensorState](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/traits/sensorstate) trait also doesn't mention anything about temperature notifications.

Is there any way to have proactive notifications for thermostat or any custom proactive notifications in general?

Answer (score 0):

Proactive notifications for Thermostats are not available right now. We will send your feedback to the smart home team for the feature request of temperature notification . In the meantime, I would suggest to open up a feature request on the [public issue tracker](https://buganizer.corp.google.com/).